# Appending values of dict list

Tags: python

I'm making a sample program that counts how many occurrences a character is in a given word. Say "Good",g occurred once,o occurred 2 times etc. Now I wanna try to further this by having a list as the value of my dictionary,increasing the first element(index 0) by 1 each time an existing character is found and appending the same list of the dict value by the Index of the character in the word
e.g. Word="Programming is nature"
Dict={'a':[2,5,16],'i':[2,8,12]...etc}

So the first index of each dict value increases by the occurrence of a character(i.e +1 if the character is found) but the other values in the list are appended(holding the location a char is found in the word). I have this for the counting alone but not for the indexing

```
def count(word):
    v=0;b={}
    b.clear()
    while word[v] in word:
        if word[v] in b.keys():
            b[word[v]]+=1;v+=1
        else:
            b[word[v]]=1;v+=1
        if v==(len(word)):
            break
    print("\n",b)


word=input("Enter word: ")
count(word)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) instead:

```
import collections

def count(word):
    c = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for index, letter in enumerate(word):
        c[letter] += [index]
    return c

print count('programming is nature')
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'a': [5, 16], ' ': [11, 14], 'e': [20], 'g': [3, 10], 'i': [8, 12], 'm': [6, 7], 'o': [2], 'n': [9, 15], 'p': [0], 's': [13], 'r': [1, 4, 19], 'u': [18], 't': [17]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution:

```
def count(word):
    b={}
    for i,letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter not in b:
            b[letter]=[0]
        b[letter][0]+=1
        b[letter].append(i)
return b
```

print(count("Programming is nature"))

word="Programming is nature"
print(count(word))

Works exactly the way you want it to. :)

Output:

```
{'a': [2, 5, 16], ' ': [2, 11, 14], 'e': [1, 20], 'g': [2, 3, 10], 'i': [2, 8, 12], 'm': [2, 6, 7], 'o': [1, 2], 'n': [2, 9, 15], 'P': [1, 0], 's': [1, 13], 'r': [3, 1, 4, 19], 'u': [1, 18], 't': [1, 17]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so some notes first.

You should be using [raw_input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of [input](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input); `input` evaluates what you enter as Python code, `raw_input` gets input from stdin (ignore this if you're using Python 3).
If you have a specific, default value your dict values can take, [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) is very useful.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def count(word):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    appearances = defaultdict(list)
    for pos, val in enumerate(word)
        counts[val] += 1
        appearances[c].append(pos)

    print 'counts:', counts
    print 'appearances:', appearances

word = input("Enter word: ")
count(word)
```

`defaultdict` takes a callable as its argument, so if you do:

```
x = defaultdict(int)
x['b'] += 1
```

since `'b'` is not a key in x, it initializes it to the value of `int()` (which is zero).

Comment: Judging by OP's use of `print()` and `input()` he could be using Python 3, where `raw_input` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Python 2.7+, use [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('abchfdhbah')
Counter({'h': 3, 'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'f': 1})
>>> the_count = Counter('abchfdhbah')
>>> the_count['h']
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `defaultdict` a little differently:

```
from collections import defaultdict
example = 'Programming is nature'
D=defaultdict(lambda: [0])
for i,c in enumerate(example):
    D[c][0] += 1
    D[c].append(i)
for k,v in D.items():
    print(k,v)
```

Output matching your example:

```
a [2, 5, 16]
  [2, 11, 14]
e [1, 20]
g [2, 3, 10]
i [2, 8, 12]
m [2, 6, 7]
o [1, 2]
n [2, 9, 15]
P [1, 0]
s [1, 13]
r [3, 1, 4, 19]
u [1, 18]
t [1, 17]
```