# How to stop the values from overwriting themselves in a dictionary: Python

Tags: python, dictionary

It was difficult to describe the question I had so let me lay out the scenario and what I have:

```
listofkeys=[]
listofvalues=[]
for it in practice_list:
    it1= it[0:5]
    it2= it[8:19]
    listofkeys.append(it1)
    listofvalues.append(it2)
di = dict(zip(listofkeys, listofvalues))
```

This prints something that for security reasons I can't display, but for the original strings in practice_list there are names that repeat and have different values for instance: ['apple is green','apple is red','banana is yellow'...]. When I split this list with listofnames and listofcolors by indexing and then zip into a dictionary it basically outputs : {'apple': 'red', 'banana':yellow'...}. The for loop seems to be overwriting the other value right? How can I stop this and have the dictionary print {'apple': 'green', 'red', 'banana':yellow'...}

Comment: You  can only have one value per key, which of course could be a list if you wanted multiple items in it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appending values of dict list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279804/appending-values-of-dict-list)

Comment: `dict` objects are maps, they map a *single* hashable object to a *single* other object. Of course, the value can be some form of container, like a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The for loop seems to be overwriting the other value right?

No; the loop stores every key-value pair into `listofkeys` and `listofvalues` accordingly, no problem there.

However, a `dict` can only have one value per key, and its keys must be unique. When the `dict` constructor runs through the `zip`ped lists, it makes key assignments one at a time, in order. If a key appears multiple times, its value is therefore replaced each time it's encountered.

The simplest way to ensure that the *first* value is used for a given key, then, is to just go through the lists in reverse order (for example, by providing the `reversed()` version of the lists to `zip`).